# Create mongo image having initial collections with docker file

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a custom mongo image from the official image with few custom collections baked into the image.

I have created a init script that runs and import json into the database using mongoimport.

Docker file builds correctly and I can see the scripts runs successfully.

But when i run the container with the generated image I am unable to see the added collecitons.
Docker file:

```
FROM mongo:latest

RUN mkdir -p /data/db2 \
    && echo "dbpath = /data/db2" > /etc/mongodb.conf \
    && chown -R mongodb:mongodb /data/db2

COPY ./upload.json /json/
COPY ./init.sh .

RUN ./init.sh

VOLUME /data/db2

CMD ["mongod", "--config", "/etc/mongodb.conf"]

#docker build -f Dockerfile -t my-mongo/test:1.0 .
```

init.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --dbpath /data/db2
mongoimport -d testStore -c authors --file ./json/upload.json --jsonArray
mongod --dbpath /data/db2 --shutdown
```

upload.json:

```
[
  { "Name": "Design Patterns", "Price": 54.93, "Category": "Computers", "Author": "Ralph Johnson" },
  { "Name": "Clean Code", "Price": 43.15, "Category": "Computers", "Author": "Robert C. Martin" }
]
```

Comment: _"... when i run the container with the generated image ..."_  What command do you use to do this?

Comment: You can't add data to mongo when building the docker image. You could create an `ENTRYPOINT` entrypoint script which first runs `init.sh` and then your `CMD`

Comment: @rickhg12hs I used the following command 
docker run --name mongodb -p 27017:27017 -v d:/mongo-data/db:/data/db2 -d my-mongo/test:1.0

Comment: I'm a docker noob, so please pardon any wrongly asked or naive questions.  Are you trying to use a [docker managed volume or a host bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)?